# How to fix recursion?

Tags: php, algorithm, recursion

I have written recurie, that shows tree.

Structure database is:

```
id | name | value | children
1    Auto   1       [2,3,5]
```

I get all rows from Db and pass then to function `getValuesParametersByID()`:

```
public function getValuesParametersByID($data = array(), $additional_parameters = array())
    {



        foreach ($data as $k => $value) {

            if (is_array($value['children']) && count($value['children']) > 0) {

                $id = (string)$value["_id"];

                $list[] = ['id' => $id, 'title' => $value["name"], "value" => $value["value"]];
                $list[]['nodes'] = $this->getChildren($all, $value['children']);

            } else {

                $id = (string)$value["_id"];
                $list[] = ['id' => $id, 'title' => $value["name"], "value" => $value["value"], 'nodes' => []];
            }
        }

        return $list;
    }


    private function getChildren($all, $childs)
    {

        $list = [];

        foreach ($childs as $k => $child) {

            if (is_array($all[$child]['children'])) {

                $children_short = $all[$child];
                $tmpArray = ["title" => $children_short["name"], "value" => $children_short["value"]];
                $tmpArray['nodes'] = $this->getChildren($all, $all[$child]['children']);

            } else {

                $tmpArray = $all[$child];
            }

            $list[] = $tmpArray;
        }

        return $list;

    }
```

Sometimes it does not add to node fields: `id, title, value.`

You can see result of function here in JSON format:

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=1313e47e7cccaac3095cabee9313005a

You can see that the second element of array has only  one `nodes` field.

I assume, that problem in this part of code:

```
} else {

    $tmpArray = $all[$child];
}
```